# Transparency control with buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, processing

I am trying to create an sketch that shows a primary color, then you control its transparency either with a button or a slider. I am using CntrolP5 library. Problem is, whenever I put the transparency variable into the color() everything gets messed up, and colors do not even appear.

see code:

```
 import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

int transparency;
color c = color(0, 160, 25);
color red;
color green;
color blue;


void setup() {
    size(400, 600);
    gui();

    red = color(255, 0, 0, transparency); // WHWENEVER I PUT TRASNPARENCY VALUE DOES NOT WORK
    green = color(0, 255, 0, transparency);
    blue = color(0, 0, 255, transparency);
    noStroke();
    smooth();

  }
  // create gui
void gui() {

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  // create radio button


  cp5.addRadioButton("radio")
    .setPosition(40, 200)
    .setItemWidth(20)
    .setItemHeight(20)
    .addItem("red", 0)
    .addItem("green", 1)
    .addItem("blue", 2)
    .setColorLabel(color(255))
    .activate(2)

  ;

  cp5.addRadioButton("level")
    .setPosition(100, 200)
    .setItemWidth(20)
    .setItemHeight(20)
    .addItem("ONE", 0)
    .addItem("TWO", 1)
    .addItem("THREE", 2)
    .addItem("FOUR", 3)
    .addItem("FIVE", 4)
    .addItem("SIX", 5)
    .addItem("SEVEN", 6)
    .addItem("EIGHT", 7)
    .addItem("NINE", 8)
    .addItem("TEN", 9)
    .setColorLabel(color(255))
    .activate(2)

  ;

  //add slider bar


  /* cp5.addSlider("level")
    .setPosition(60,20)
    .setSize(100,20)
    .setRange(0,10)
    .setValue(5)
    .setNumberOfTickMarks(11)
    .setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE)
    ;*/

}


void radio(int theC) {
  switch (theC) {
    case (0):
      c = red;
      break;
    case (1):
      c = green;
      break;
    case (2):
      c = blue;
      break;

  }
}

void level(int theC) {
  switch (theC) {
    case (0):
      transparency = 15;
      break;
    case (1):
      transparency = 13;
      break;
    case (2):
      transparency = 11;
      break;
    case (3):
      transparency = 9;
      break;
    case (4):
      transparency = 7;
      break;
    case (5):
      transparency = 6;
      break;
    case (6):
      transparency = 5;
      break;
    case (7):
      transparency = 4;
      break;
    case (8):
      transparency = 2;
      break;
    case (9):
      transparency = 1;
      break;

  }
}

void draw() {
  background(220);

  fill(c); //fill with color

  ellipse(200, 400, 100, 100);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized variables for color (red, green, blue) inside `setup()` and you never change them. If you want to change transparency you need to move in into `draw()` and also variable `transparency` need to be initialized to some value.

Also you change color only if user click on "radio" buttons to improve this you need to abstract color logic from `radio()

```
void radio(int theC) {
  mode = theC;
}
```

Where `mode` is integer variable storing your color mode. And updated `draw()` function:

```
void draw() {
  background(220);

  switch (mode) {
    case (0):
      c = color(255, 0, 0, transparency);
      break;
    case (1):
      c = color(0, 255, 0, transparency);
      break;
    case (2):
      c = color(0, 0, 255, transparency);
      break;    
  }

  fill(c); //fill with color
  ellipse(200, 400, 100, 100);
}
```

As @rlinden correctly mentioned you should also update alpha values to 0-255.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is not complete. It is difficult to see, for instance, when `setup()` is called. If it is just at the beginning (like a setup), then your `transparency` variable probably has value 0 (because it was not initialized) and the colors will be fully transparent.

Second of all, the alpha value is supposed to be a float between 0.0 and 1.0 or an integer between 0 and 255. In your case, you are setting the transparency values very low (the highest is 15), so your colors will be pretty much transparent. Try using this instead:

```
void level(int theC) {
  switch (theC) {
    case (0):
      transparency = 255;
      break;
    case (1):
      transparency = 230;
      break;
    case (2):
      transparency = 200;
      break;
    case (3):
      transparency = 170;
      break;
    case (4):
      transparency = 140;
      break;
    case (5):
      transparency = 110;
      break;
    case (6):
      transparency = 80;
      break;
    case (7):
      transparency = 50;
      break;
    case (8):
      transparency = 20;
      break;
    case (9):
      transparency = 0;
      break;

  }
}
```

I hope it helps.